# What are some intuition behind how much time it takes for my piece of code to run?

Tags: java, arraylist, operating-system, cpu

What are some intuition behind how much time it takes for my piece of code to run? (i.e. how much time does it take to add 100 objects into an ArrayList in java?)

To clarify, I'm not looking for timers. I'm looking for low-level discussions on how long each instruction takes. For example, assuming we have the following set-up

```
Object[] array = new Object[100];
currentIndex = 0;
// I call myList.add(myObject);
```

How long does each instruction take:

Instruction 1:

the first Object pointer in the array will reference myObject?

Instruction 2:

```
currentIndex++
```

Instruction 3:

```
if(currentIndex>100) 
// resize internal array
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you'd like to know?

Comment: Asking for "intuition" is another word for asking for an opinion.  Answers here are expected to be based on facts and experience, not opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TimeTest1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      long total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
         total += i;
      }

      long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      System.out.println(elapsedTime);
   }
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

**There's absolutely no "intuition" whatsoever.** You have to measure.

And benchmark.

And profile.

And test.

---

In modern computing environments, there are just so many (bigger and smaller) details that the actual execution speed of a particular operation depends on, that it's practically impossible to tell "intuitively" how long it will take to execute it.

If you have data about the computational complexity of your algorithm, you may be able to come up with approximations with regards to the **change** in (ratio of) execution times as a function of the change in (ratio of) the input sizes. But that's a completely different beast.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

//do something - add 100 objects in ArrayList

long endTime = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println(endTime - startTime);
```